# Why Apache Kafka doesn't support ephemeral topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

Having a distributed log is great but I see good use cases for ephemeral topics as well so I wonder Why Apache Kafka doesn't support ephemeral topics?

Comment: why do you say so? Just set your desired retention time, if you want it to delete the data after a short period of time; Or set the retention bytes value, if you want it to delete data after certain size is reached. It may be something philosophical: is the topic, or the data inside the topic, which is ephemeral? hah..

Comment: @AsierAranbarri Good Question. By ephemeral I mean in memory since deleting the actual data from disk is an expensive process.

Comment: oh, i get your point now @user1870400. They already replied, but you can play with flush parameters and the amount of memory you are giving for cache to the broker. It is not something "natural" in kafka, but you could find some ways.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Kafka can save messages in memory and after a specific time or number of messages flushes them to the disk.

see `log.flush.interval.messages` and `log.flush.interval.ms` in [Broker configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs).

Comment: Better leave the two parameters to their default values, by default `log.flush.interval.messages` and `log.flush.interval.ms` is Long.MaxValue